# How do we set cron job in social engine?

Tags: socialengine, cron-task

I am working on a social engine project and it has a module through wich an automatic email is send to users every morning. I have already created an action on the controller of the module which will send email to users. I would like to set it up under cron job tasks
How can we do that? 
could you please show an example to set up it at 9 am every day?

Comment: You can use Task Scheduler to set cron jobs in SE
http://social-engine-tutorials.blogspot.in/2012_06_01_archive.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Task scheduler is already there in the admin panel which uses cron job, you can edit settings of cron job using `settings/task scheduler/task scheduler settings` in the admin panel.

refer links:
 [cron job](http://support.socialengine.com/questions/222/Admin-Panel-Settings-Task-Scheduler)